# Count number of books in Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, count, hashmap, hashset

I am new to Java programming and studying it at school.

We have been given an assignment to create a small library, with the following classes Library, Book, Author and Copy. With a given class Biblio which has predefined code and adds the books to the class book in an arraylist in Class Copy.

The UML Domain is attached so you know the flow of the classes 
Everything is working fine and the generated output is correct.

There is just one method in class Library that is not working, the int method has to count the number of Copy's based on the Class Book (String): 
I have to go through the Arraylist in Class Copy and look for a specific book and return the number of copy's. 
Sorry for the Dutch language in the code. 
I have tried multiple steps using a for loop 
Now I have found a similar post the uses hashset, I have tried below code but the return comes back with 0. (There are 3 copy's)

```
package domein;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import domein.Boek;
import domein.Exemplaar;

/**
 *
 * Klasse die verantwoordelijk is voor het beheer van boeken
 *
 */
public class Bibliotheek {
  private ArrayList < Exemplaar > boekenlijst = new ArrayList < Exemplaar > ();


  /**
   *
   * Print de naam van de Bibliiotheek.
   *
   */
  public Bibliotheek(String string) {
    System.out.println(string);

  }

  /**
   * Methode om een alle exmeplaren van de opgegeven boek toe te voegen aan de
   * lijst.
   *
   * @param b1
   * @param exemplaar
   */

  public void voegToe(Boek b1, int exemplaar) {
    for (int i = 0; i < exemplaar; i++) {
      Exemplaar e = new Exemplaar(b1, exemplaar);
      boekenlijst.add(e);

    }

  }

  /**
   * Methode om een boek toe te voegen aan de lijst.
   *
   * @param b2
   */
  public void voegToe(Boek b2) {

    Exemplaar f = new Exemplaar(b2, 1);

    boekenlijst.add(f);
  }

  /**
   * Hiermee worden alle boeken van de bibliotheek opgevraagd en getoond op het
   * scherm.
   *
   * @return
   */
  public ArrayList < String > toonCollectie() {
    ArrayList < String > titels = new ArrayList < String > ();
    for (Exemplaar boek: boekenlijst) {

      System.out.println("Exemplaar --> " + boek.getTitel() + " " + boek.getAuteur() + " in taal " + boek.getTaal());
    }
    return titels;
  }

  /**
   * Hiermee worden alle Engelse boeken van de bibliotheek opgevraagd en worden
   * de exemeplaren in het Engels getoond op het scherm.
   *
   * @param string
   * @return
   */
  public ArrayList < Exemplaar > toonCollectie(String string) {
    for (Exemplaar boek: boekenlijst) {
      if (boek.getTaal() == string)

        System.out.println("Exemplaar --> " + boek.getTitel() + " " + boek.getAuteur() + " in taal " + boek.getTaal());
    }
    return boekenlijst;

  }

  /**
   * Hiermee worden alle auteurs welke een prijs hebben opgevraagd in de
   * bibliotheek en degene met een prijs worden op het scherm getoond.
   *
   * @return
   */
  public boolean printAuteurs() {
    for (Exemplaar auteur: boekenlijst)
      if (auteur.getPrijs(true))
        System.out.println(auteur.getAuteur());
    return false;

  }

  /**
   * Een methode om door de boekenlijst te gaan en de totaal aantal exemplaren
   * op te vragen.
   *
   * @param b1
   * @return
   */

  public int telExemplaren(Boek b1) {
    Set < String > set = new HashSet < String > ();
    int count = 0;
    for (Exemplaar element: boekenlijst) {
      String names = element.getTitel();
      set.add(names);
    }

    for (String a: set) {
      for (Exemplaar element: boekenlijst) {
        String names = element.getTitel();
        if (a.equals(names)) {
          count++;
        }
      }

      count = 0;
    }

    return count;

  }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. I have added the complete code

Comment: It's a little hard to tell with the Dutch names, but if you're talking about `telExemplaren()`, I believe you are not using the parameter to the method (`Boek b1`) at all inside it. So no matter what book you'll pass it, it will always do the same.

Comment: It is a little confusing because you're using `for (Exemplaar element: boekenlijst)` to populate the set, then going through those same values and checking it against itself once more

Comment: The last thing you're doing in your outer for loop is setting count back to 0. How is it supposed to return anything but 0 when it is set to 0 right before the loop exits?

Comment: gknicker's method works. I was looking in the wrong direction. That is why I started to use Hashset and the code itself works, but not as a getmethode. Setting the count =0; outside loop resets the int back when it is going through the Arraylist and so it returns the correct number instead of increasing the number it returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `telExemplaren()` method completely ignores the `Boek b1` parameter.

Perhaps this is what you wanted to do?

```
public int telExemplaren(Boek b1) {
  int count = 0;
  for (Exemplaar element: boekenlijst) {
    if (b1.getTitel().equals(element.getTitel())) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was trying a similar but used contains and that doesn't work. I was looking for all kinds of methods and I guess I was looking in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the line

```
count = 0;
```

from near the end of the function should help it do something more useful than currently.